# How to hide header value from react native calendar (expendable calendar) also how to add Knob in it

Tags: react-native, calendar, react-native-calendars

I have implemented ExpandableCalendar via react-native-calendars, now i needs to hide header title and Please help me to Knob on expandableCalender [image: Please find out screenshot where i needs to hide January 2020 and needs to change Knob to down arrow]

Please help me.. Thanks in advance